# NSTableView Always Selects First Row on Application Launch

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

This may seem like an easy problem, but I honestly can't figure out how to solve it.  Whenever I launch my application, The first row of my `NSTableView` is always selected.  I want the default behavior of the table view to be no selected rows.  How can I accomplish this in the Interface Builder portion of Xcode4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using an `NSArrayController` to provide content for the `NSTableView`, then make sure the "Avoid empty selection" property is unchecked for the array controller.

Otherwise, what version of OS X are you seeing this behavior in?

Comment: The Avoid Empty Selection checkbox is unchecked, and I'm still having the same issue.  I'm currently using Lion.

Answer (score 7):

In interface builder's `NSTableView` properties tab select "Empty selection" checkbox.

Comment: The empty selection box is checked, but the first row is still being selected.

Answer (score 2):

An other reason that can cause the first line to be always selected:
If you are using bindings to populate the tableview, make sure the option "Avoid Empty Selection" is unchecked in your NSArrayController.

Comment: This is the logical explanation to this behavior. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 5 on Mavericks, this works for me:

uncheck "Select Inserted Objects" of the Array Controller.

Thx for the hints provided on this page!

Answer (score 1):

What about calling `[tableview deselectAll]` in your `awakeFromNib`?

Comment: @LandonSchropp the ideal solution is posted below.